# How to bring multiple i item inside the same tab tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to bring multiple i item inside the same tab tabpanel.

I have a tabPanel where in first tab I am have button. While clicking on the button of tab1 i want to display panel3 instead of panel. Is any work around for that.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width : 200,
    height : 200,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    items : [{
        title : 'tab1',
        items : [{
            xtype :"panel",
            itemId : "panel1"
        },{
            xtype : "button"
        }]
    }, {
        title : 'tab2',
        items : [{
            xtype :"panel",
            itemId : "panel2"
        }]
    }]
});

//

{
    xtype :"panel",
    itemId : "panel3"
}
```

Is there any help while clicking on button i can load new component called "panel3"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [card](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.Card.html) if you planning change between `panel3` and `tabpanel` with the ability to switch back

```
var tab = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            items: [{
                title: 'tab1',
                items: [{
                    xtype: "panel",
                    itemId: "panel1"
                }, {
                    xtype: "butt
                    on",
                    text: 'change panel',
                    handler: function () {
                        mainPanel.getLayout().next()
                        // mainPanel.remove(tab);
                        // mainPannel.add(panel);
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                title: 'tab2',
                items: [{
                    xtype: "panel",
                    itemId: "panel2"
                }]
            }]
        });

        //

        var panel = Ext.widget({
            xtype: "panel",
            itemId: "panel3",
            html: 'Hi, I`m panel3'
        })

        var mainPanel = Ext.widget({
            layout: 'card',
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [tab, panel]
        })
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/376c)

Or you can just remove tabpanel and add panel

Comment: this is correct but I want to render `panel3` in place of `panel1`. not as a seperate in screen. On click of button tab1 has two itms panel1 and button, I want to render just panel3.